# How to access non-contiguous range in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, range

First, What I want to do is do regression analysis like below.

```
Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Regress", RngY, RngX, False, False, 95, RngOut, False, False, False, False, , False
```

The problem is, when p value of explanatory variable(I mean X-axis) over 0.05, I need to delete that variable from explanatory variable.

However, I cannot delete data from worksheet. Because I do many other regression analysis with that data.

So My solution is assign the data with Range variable in the code.

```
Dim RngX1 As Range
Dim RngX2 As Range
Dim RngX3 As Range
...
Dim RngX20 As Range
Dim XAxisRng As range

Set XAxisRng = Nothing

Set RngX1 = ActiveSheet.Range("A1","A100")
Set RngX2 = ActiveSheet.Range("B1","B100")
Set RngX3 = ActiveSheet.Range("C1","C100")
...
Set RngX20 = ActiveSheet.Range("T1","T100")
```

When I do first regression analysis so get the result : For example RngX2 has p-value over 0.05!.
Then I only use two Range 1. RngX1, 2. RngX3

```
For j = 1 to 50 '''I need to do regression analysis 50 cases with the same dataset.
   For i = 1 to 20
      If pval < 0.05 Then '''Only the range which have p-value below 0.05 can be included in explanatory variable.
         XAxisRng = Union(XAxisRng , RngX & i) 
      End If
   Next i
   Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Regress", RngY, XAxisRng , False, False, 95, RngOutcome, False, False, False, False, , False
Next j
```

But It doesn't work.

How Can I do this job?

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work", do you mean that you're getting an error?  Or is your code just not doing what you expect?  Also, what is the variable `RngX`?  If you are trying to use `Union(XAxisRng, RngX & i)` to construct your `Range` variable names, that will not work.

Comment: @TehDrunkSailor It gets the error. Also, you are right. (RngX & i) It is for constructing variable names such as RngX1, RngX5, else... I think I can solve this problem if I can construct my range variable names.

Comment: What error are you getting?  What line is causing the error?  These are very useful pieces of information for people trying to help you.  And again, trying to construct variable names like you're doing will not work.  I can guarantee that `Union` statement will cause an error.